# D3.js dragging with inertia

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to make dragging with inertia using d3.js and have a problem that there are some visual jerks in inertia effect, that's especially noticeable if circle will be dragged and released quickly.

Ideally it should work as google maps: when mouse was released circle should continue to moving smoothly for a while in the same direction and then stop.

Some good example can be found here http://bl.ocks.org/pjanik/raw/5872514/, but it implements by updating of source code of d3.js (not official I guess), while I'm interesting in implementation using official releases of d3.js.

Any suggestions on that?

```js
var svg = d3.select('#parent')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', '100%')
  .attr('height', '100%');
var g = svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', "translate(450, 250) scale(1)");

var circle = d3.select('g')
  .append('circle')
  .attr('class', 'circle')
  .attr('r', 20);

function zoomed() {
  var transform = d3.event.transform;
  g.attr('transform', transform);
}

var mouseEvents = [];

var zoomFunction = d3.zoom().on('zoom', function() {
    zoomed();
    if (d3.event.sourceEvent) {
      mouseEvents.push(d3.event);

      if (mouseEvents.length > 5) {
        mouseEvents.shift();
      }
    }
  })
  .on('end', function() {
    if (d3.event.sourceEvent && mouseEvents.length) {
      let lastEvent = mouseEvents.shift();
      let x1 = lastEvent.sourceEvent.pageX;
      let y1 = lastEvent.sourceEvent.pageY;
      let t1 = lastEvent.sourceEvent.timeStamp;
      let x2 = d3.event.sourceEvent.pageX;
      let y2 = d3.event.sourceEvent.pageY;
      let t2 = d3.event.sourceEvent.timeStamp;

      let minDistance = 20;
      // Deltas
      var dX = x2 - x1,
        dY = y2 - y1,
        dMs = Math.max(t2 - t1, 1);

      // Speeds
      var speedX = Math.max(Math.min(dX / dMs, 1), -1);
      var speedY = Math.max(Math.min(dY / dMs, 1), -1);

      // Distance moved (Euclidean distance)
      var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2));

      if (distance > minDistance) {
        var position = d3.event.transform;

        var newLeft = position.x + (speedX * distance * 0.6),
          newTop = position.y + (speedY * distance * 0.6);

        svg
          .transition()
          .duration(350)
          .call(
            zoomFunction.transform,
            d3.zoomIdentity.translate(newLeft, newTop).scale(1)
          );
      }
    }

    mouseEvents = [];
  });

d3.zoom().translateBy(svg, 450, 250);
d3.zoom().scaleBy(svg, 1);
svg.call(zoomFunction).on('dblclick.zoom', null);
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 900px;
  height: 500px;
}

.circle {
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id='parent'></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`d3-inertia`](https://github.com/Fil/d3-inertia), which is a package that handles exactly this. I used [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/Fil/a034e32156b7b25ee9054c1bc50dc0ca) as inspiration and got the following result:

```js
var position = [450, 250];
var width = 500,
  height = 300,
  radius = 20;

var svg = d3.select('#parent')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height);
var g = svg.append('g');

function draw() {
  g.attr('transform', `translate(${position[0]}, ${position[1]})`);
}

draw();

var circle = d3.select('g')
  .append('circle')
  .attr('class', 'circle')
  .attr('r', radius);

/* Function to keep the ball inside the view */
function updatePosition(newPosition, offset) {
  if (offset === undefined) {
    offset = {x: 0, y: 0};
  }
  newPosition[0] = Math.max(radius, Math.min(newPosition[0] + offset.x, width - radius));
  newPosition[1] = Math.max(radius, Math.min(newPosition[1] + offset.y, height - radius));
  position = newPosition;
}

function getTransformParameters(transformString) {
  var values = transformString.substr("translate(".length)
    .split(",")
    .map(function(d) {
      return parseInt(d, 10);
    });
  return { x: values[0], y: values[1] };
}

var offset = { x: 0, y: 0 };
var inertia = d3.inertiaHelper({
  start: function() {
    var transform = getTransformParameters(g.attr("transform"));
    offset = {
      x: transform.x - inertia.position[0],
      y: transform.y - inertia.position[1]
    };
  },
  move: function() {
    updatePosition(inertia.position, offset);
    draw();
  },
  render: function(t) {
    updatePosition([
      // velocity is constant, so I use t**2 to make it look like it slows down
      // 0.25 is just to slow down the ball so it doesn't fly off
      inertia.position[0] + 0.25 * t ** 2 * inertia.velocity[0],
      inertia.position[1] + 0.25 * t ** 2 * inertia.velocity[1]
    ]);
    draw();
  }
});

svg.call(
  d3.drag()
  .on("start", inertia.start)
  .on("drag", inertia.move)
  .on("end", inertia.end)
);
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 900px;
  height: 500px;
}

.circle {
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-inertia"></script>
<div id='parent'></div>
```

Comment: thank you! d3-inertia provides expected behavior. but I've noticed that it keeps circle centered when dragging is started, it comes from d3.drag and it uses mouse as coordinates for circle center. can it be an expected behavior for dragging?

Comment: found a solution that works for me: event contains dx and dy values that actual changes of element from previous position. having 'transform' attribute I can change position of element on this deltas to get expected position:
`.on('drag', function () {
                    /* getTransformParameters should return current element position */
                    const params = getTransformParameters(gElement.attr('transform'));
                    inertia.move({ x: params.width + event.dx, y: params.height + event.dy });
                })`

Comment: I'd do it differently. In my experience, hacking around a library like this is a recipe for bugs. I've updated my answer with a solution. I calculate the difference between the transform and `inertia.position` only at the start, and draw the ball using that difference. That means if you drag the left corner of the ball, if will always keep at the left corner.